# Perl can't find module when run from cron.daily

Tags: perl, cron, perl-module

I have perl programs that use `Net::Finger` and have run successfully from `cron.daily` in Fedora 11.
I just upgraded a server to Fedora 18 and these same perl programs no longer run from cron but run fine from command line when logged in as root.
The error is:

```
Can't locate Net/Finger.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .)
```

The path to the module is `/root/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/Finger.pm` but I can't figure out how to add the path without causing more errors.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Such an odd place for it to be installed! Is there a reason it's not installed in the expected directory? There's permission issues to consider too.

Comment: @ikegami: a local::lib installation for *root*, maybe?

Comment: @ysth, I know *how* it can be done. It's the *why* that's curious.

Comment: I meant it might have been accidental

Comment: Consider letting another user than root run that job. Do you really need root's power to do the job?

Comment: I was logged in as root and ran cpan Net::Finger and that's where it put it.  Should I have done something different?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See [`perlfaq8`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfaq8#How_do_I_add_a_directory_to_my_include_path_%28@INC%29_at_runtime?).

Here are three ways to add arbitrary directories to Perl's module search path.

1. Set the `PERL5LIB` environment variable

   ```
   15 15 * * 1-5 PERL5LIB=/root/perl5/lib/perl5 /usr/local/bin/perl my_script.pl
   ```
2. Use the `-I` command line switch

   ```
   15 15 * * 1-5 /usr/local/bin/perl -I/root/perl5/lib/perl5 my_script.pl
   ```
3. Use the `lib` pragma inside your perl script

   ```
   #! /usr/local/bin/perl
   # my_script.pl: the script that does my thing
   use lib '/root/perl5/lib/perl5';
   use Net::Finger;
   ...
   ```

---

Also note that the environment of a cron job is much sparser than the environment of your command line, and in particular the cron environment's `$PATH` variable might not be what you expect. If you're not specifying the full path to the Perl executable, verify what `$PATH` the cron environment is using and make sure you are running the right version of perl.

Comment: Thanks.  This program also uses DBI ... which perl has no problem finding from cron so it's probably in a different place.  If I use the lib with path will it still be able to find DBI ? In other words, does it add the specified library to the existing environment or replace it ?

Comment: All of these methods add (prepend, really) to the search path. If you had another module called `DBI.pm` under `/root/perl5/lib/perl5`, then perl would load that one instead of the system one.

Comment: This question/answer saved me.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you add this to the top of the script?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use lib "/root/perl5/lib/perl5/Net";
```

Was this previously set in the `.profile`?

This is from a ubuntu thread, but may be related:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work
*Cron passes a minimal set of environment variables to your jobs. To see the difference, add a dummy job like this:

```
* * * * * env > /tmp/env.output*
```

I don't have a linux box handy at the moment, but I would try to see what's different in the @INC by running the following logged in as root and trying to set up a job to see what the crontab has. The `env` output above may indicate a different shell is being used by crontab, than what you may have set when logging in as root.

log in as root and run:

```
perl -le 'print for @INC'
```

set up a cron job to see the differences. I'm not sure if this syntax will work, but you could put the command in a simple pl script.

```
* * * * * perl -le 'print for @INC' > /tmp/inc.output
```

do the same for env

Comment: perl -le 'print for @INC' returns:  `/root/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi  
/root/perl5/lib/perl5  
/usr/local/lib64/perl5  
/usr/local/share/perl5  
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl  
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl  
/usr/lib64/perl5  
/usr/share/perl5`  The cron jobs did not produce any output in /tmp

Comment: I see why the cron jobs did not produce any output ... got "bad username" error in cron log.  What username did you want me to use?

Comment: I tried entering root as the username in the crontab and got this:  `[root@sendmail tmp]# cat env.output  
MAILTO=root  
SHELL=/bin/bash  
USER=root  
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin  
PWD=/root  
SHLVL=1  
HOME=/root  
LOGNAME=root  
_=/bin/env  
[root@sendmail tmp]# cat inc.output  
/usr/local/lib64/perl5  
/usr/local/share/perl5  
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl  
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl  
/usr/lib64/perl5  
/usr/share/perl5`